# Oracle SQL - Pre-insert SUM

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to update records on a table with the following criteria.

The update is a calculation of the number rows, multiplied by a multiplier and then apportioned over the total amount of the calculation.  I have managed to achieve most of this.  However, I need to find a way of getting a SUM of the rows in my select already interpreted and deduct that from the calculations for any rows about to be updated.

Is there a way of adding/summing the values I've manipulated before I update them to a table to be used in the query?

It is the running total of t2.primary_column10 that I need to evaluate.

```
SELECT t2.primary_column1
      ,t2.primary_column2
      ,t2.primary_column3
      ,t2.primary_column4
      ,CASE
          WHEN (primary_column6 > variable1)
            OR primary_column8 = variable2
          THEN
             CASE
                WHEN t2.primary_column7 > (variable1 - SUM(t2.primary_column10) OVER ())
                THEN
                   (variable1 - SUM(t2.primary_column10) OVER ())
                ELSE
                   t2.primary_column7
             END
          ELSE
             CASE
                WHEN t2.primary_column11 > t2.primary_column7 THEN t2.primary_column7
                ELSE t2.primary_column11
             END
       END
          AS primary_column5
  FROM (SELECT t3.primary_column1
              ,t3.primary_column2
              ,t3.primary_column3
              ,t3.primary_column4
              ,t3.primary_column11
              ,t3.primary_column7
              ,t3.primary_column9
              ,t3.primary_column6
              ,CASE
                  WHEN (t3.primary_column6 > variable1)
                    OR t3.primary_column8 = variable2
                  THEN
                     CASE
                        WHEN t3.primary_column7 < (FLOOR( variable1/(t3.primary_column6) * t3.primary_column11))
                        THEN
                           t3.primary_column7
                        ELSE
                           (FLOOR( variable1 / (t3.primary_column6) * t3.primary_column11))
                     END
                  ELSE
                     CASE
                        WHEN t3.primary_column11 > t3.primary_column7 THEN t3.primary_column7
                        ELSE t3.primary_column11
                     END
               END
                  AS primary_column10
          FROM (SELECT primary_column1
                      ,primary_column2
                      ,primary_column3
                      ,primary_column4
                      ,primary_column7
                      ,primary_column11
                      ,UPPER( primary_column8) AS primary_column8
                      ,SUM( primary_column11) OVER () AS primary_column6
                  FROM table_name1
                       LEFT OUTER JOIN (  SELECT primary_column1
                                                ,primary_column2
                                                ,primary_column3
                                                ,primary_column4
                                                ,COUNT( *) AS primary_column7
                                                ,SUM( COUNT( *)) OVER () AS primary_column9
                                            FROM table_name2
                                        GROUP BY primary_column1
                                                ,primary_column2
                                                ,primary_column3
                                                ,primary_column4) t5
                          USING (primary_column1
                                ,primary_column2
                                ,primary_column3
                                ,primary_column4)
                 WHERE primary_column6 = variable3) t3) t2;
```

Comment: Don't you think it would be helpful to show us your table structure, sample data, and actual SQL code?  We are not mind readers.

Comment: Here is what I have thus far: